# How to calculate and distribute the result on html?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have two values on my html: "Money" and "Time", and those values come from Session Storage, depending on what the person filled previously on another html page.
So lets say the person filled that they need to pay $100 in 2 days.

What i'm trying to do, is to create a list, showing the number of payments, with the amount to be paid in each payment. Like the example below

MONEY: $100 /
TIME: 2 Days

RESULT:

$50

$50

So if the person has 5 days, instead of 2, it would appear as:

$20

$20

$20

$20

$20

What i have so far is:

HTML

```
<p id="money-value"></p>
<p id="time-value"></p>

<div id="payments"></div>

<script>

const displayMoney = document.getElementById("money-value");
const storedMoney = sessionStorage.getItem("Money");
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
displayMoney.innerHTML =  "Money: " + storedMoney
});

const displayTime = document.getElementById("time-value");
const storedTime = sessionStorage.getItem("Time");
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
displayTime.innerHTML =  "Time: " + storedTime
});

</script>
```

What i'm trying to do here, is to use Javascript to create a list element, inside the `<div id="payments>` that would not only calculate the amount to be paid in each payment, but also that the number of "topics" (payments) would increase, according to the number of "time" the person has (Just like the example i gave).

Answer (score 0):

This might be the result you wanted. But I'm pretty sure that there are better ways to program this.

```js
const displayMoney = document.getElementById("money-value");
const storedMoney = 100; //example
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
displayMoney.innerHTML =  "Money: " + storedMoney
});

const displayTime = document.getElementById("time-value");
const storedTime = 5;//example
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
displayTime.innerHTML =  "Time: " + storedTime
});
var calc = storedMoney / storedTime;

for (let i = 0; i < storedTime; i++) {
    var list = document.createElement("li");
    list.innerText = `${calc}`;
    document.body.appendChild(list);
}
```

```html
    <p id="money-value"></p>
<p id="time-value"></p>

<div id="payments"></div>
```

Comment: I'm still a Javascript student as well, and i thought the function would be way more complicated than it really is!
Thanks a lot! Have a great Sunday!

Comment: Actually, for some reason, my code is resulting in one single `li` item. i dont really know what went wrong with it.

Comment: @Fadrick I’m assuming you are using the sessionstorage function again? Maybe try to find out the datatype the variable storedtime is, by doing console.log(typeof storedtime). I think you are receive a string from the sessionstorage so try to converting it to a number by using parseInt(storedtime). That’s what I think. And oh same thing goes for storedmoney. Anyways have a great evening :)

Comment: For some reason, even thou i used ParseInt, and the console is returning a number, it still won't work. It will make the calculation, and return only one result. 
I'll keep asking until i figure it out. Thanks again!